# Is there a way to create collection of objects from another in Java (LINQ-like)?

Tags: java, c#, linq

Totally newbie question: how does one get properties from one collection of objects into another in Java?

In C# I usually use LINQ's awesome syntax for this kind of task. Here's an example:

```
        List<Hero> Heroes = new List<Hero>()
        {
            new Hero() { Name = "Iron Man", Superpower = "Being Iron Man, duh", Age = 48 },
            new Hero() { Name = "Spider-Man", Superpower = "Spidey things", Age = 16 }

        };

        List<AlterEgo> AlterEgos = Heroes.Select(x => new AlterEgo { Age = x.Age }).ToList();
```

After the `.Select`, I get two `AlterEgo`s with `Age`s 48 and 16. Is there a way to do this kind of thing in Java?

Comment: `heroes.stream().map(x -> new AlterEgo(x.getAge())).collect(Collectors.toList())`

Comment: That's awesome, thanks! Also, as a follow-up: can that be done to an anonymous object, to get a collection of some properties? In C# it's:
`Heroes.Select(x => new { x.Age, x.Name }).ToList();, which becomes a List<'a> internally.

Comment: Java doesn't really have anonymous objects. But in Java 10+ you can do something like this: `var list = heroes.stream().map(x -> new Object() { int age = x.getAge(); String name = x.getName(); }).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: Awesome, that's really helpful. Would you mind posting your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) are Java's parallel of LINQ. Here's what your code would like in Java, with adaptations for style and syntax:

```
List<Hero> heroes = Arrays.asList(
        new Hero("Iron Man", "Being Iron Man, duh", 48),
        new Hero("Spider-Man", "Spidey things", 16)
);

List<AlterEgo> alterEgos = heroes.stream()
        .map(x -> new AlterEgo(x.getAge()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

As for the follow-up in the comments, Java doesn't have proper anonymous objects, but you can create instances of [anonymous classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) and access their properties, as long as you can avoid naming the type. Java 10 makes this a little easier with the `var` keyword:

```
var list = heroes.stream()
        .map(x -> new Object() {
            int age = x.getAge();
            String name = x.getName(); 
        })
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

list.forEach(x -> System.out.println(x.age));
```